# Issue with HTML li tag in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, html-lists

I am trying to display an image and some text on the same line, both the image and text are clickable and point to some link. I am using jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.
However below code shows the Stuff1 and Description being overlapped by Image, so the image is in front and text in background. I wish to have Image and text side by side, what could be the problem in my below code ?

```
   <li> 
<img src="images/someImage.png" /> 
<h3><a href="#someID" >Stuff1</a></h3> 
<p>Some Description</p> 
<a href="#someID" >Stuff2</a> 
</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example on the jQuery.mobile site, you have to wrap the whole of the inner html of the `li` in your link, like so:

```
<li> 
  <a href="#someID">
    <img src="images/someImage.png" /> 
    <h3>Stuff1</h3> 
    <p>Some Description</p>
  </a>
</li>
```

However, it looks like you may be trying to have two different links in one `li` tag.  In mobile application, this really isn't feasible (but I could be wrong about what you're tring to do)

Reference:
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/lists/lists-thumbnails.html

Comment: Except that HTML forbids block-level (h3, p) elements as children of inline-elements (a)

Comment: @david-kemp This really is subjective as most tags' block/inline status can be set via css, then it really has no bearing.  The CSS for jQuery mobile does this. You should familiarize yourself with the framework he's asking about.

Comment: Thanks @Groovetrain for providing the exact demo link. It helps. You guys are awesome.

Answer (score 0):

set `float` to everything. Also if possible insert everything apart from the image inside a `div` and then set the `img` and the `div` to `float: left`. Like:

```
<li> 
 <img src="images/someImage.png" /> 
 <div>
  <h3><a href="#someID" >Stuff1</a></h3> 
  <p>Some Description</p> 
  <a href="#someID" >Stuff2</a> 
  </div>
</li>
```

and the CSS:

```
li img{float:left;}
li div{float:left;}
```

Comment: This is not really how to do it with jQuery.mobile, but I'd say in other cases, you're right on.

Comment: @Groovetrain - I'm not sure what does jQuery.mobile has to do with this, however as you suggested to put everything inside the link would do but don't you think we'll have to set the `<a>` display to block?

Comment: Hi Naveed, I don't intend to modify the li tag for whole app, so don't really wish to modify the CSS

Comment: the subject of his question (I just re-tagged it to include jquery-mobile) says "jQuery mobile"